# Wildcard error - "invalid option"

Tags: python, cmd, wildcard

I am currently working on a python script in which there is a moment **I want to delete a file which name is ending with .txt**

To do so I just run a command line using os in python:

```
os.system("del working/*.txt")
```

When running the python script, I get the following error in cmd:

**Option non valide - "*".** which can be translated **"Invalid option"**

It seems that the wildcard isn't recognized by cmd but I know very little about this. Why is it not working ?

I know I could handle the situation with regular expressions but I'd like to understand.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Use [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) instead and make sure you turn on shell expansion (i.e. `shell=True`).

Comment: Windows' `cmd.exe` uses `/` for program options (much like you might use `-` or `--` on a Linux or macOS system). Its filesystem separator is the _backslash_: `\ `. In any case, shelling out isn't the best way to handle this. There are standard library functions to remove files.

Comment: What about using `os.remove`? (https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.remove)

Comment: why do this in python to make it platform agnostic? `for f in glob.glob('working/*.txt'): os.remove(f)`

Answer (score 2):

In Windows, `\` is the path delimiter, not `/`, so you should do:

```
os.system(r"del working\*.txt")
```

Note that `/` in Windows is for switches, hence the "invalid option" error.

Answer (score 1):

I think its better use os.remove instead os.system with "del" command. Using os.system your script will not work on linux. Here a example using os.remove:

```
files = os.listdir("working\")
for fi in files:
    if fi.endswith(".json"):
        os.remove("working\{}".fomat(fi))
```